# understanding FastText multilingual

Tags: python, text-alignment, word-embedding, fasttext

I am working with this modified version of FastText ([fastText_multilingual](https://github.com/Babylonpartners/fastText_multilingual)) that will let me align words in two languages.

I am trying to understand their fasttext.py and especially the [Fast Vector class](https://github.com/Babylonpartners/fastText_multilingual/blob/master/fasttext.py). 
In the example file [align_your_own.ipynb](https://github.com/Babylonpartners/fastText_multilingual/blob/master/align_your_own.ipynb)the authors show how to measure similarity between two words. I would like to iterate the process for the whole set of words, instead of measuring similarity every time for a single word. To do this I need to understand how to access to these FastVector objects. 
That's why I am trying to understand the Fast vector class.

I am stuck here:

```
 def __init__(self, vector_file='', transform=None):
    """Read in word vectors in fasttext format"""
    self.word2id = {}

    # Captures word order, for export() and translate methods
    self.id2word = []

    print('reading word vectors from %s' % vector_file)
    with open(vector_file, 'r') as f:
        (self.n_words, self.n_dim) = \
            (int(x) for x in f.readline().rstrip('\n').split(' '))
        self.embed = np.zeros((self.n_words, self.n_dim))
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            elems = line.rstrip('\n').split(' ')
            self.word2id[elems[0]] = i
            self.embed[i] = elems[1:self.n_dim+1]
            self.id2word.append(elems[0])
```

I have never created a class in python, so this make things more difficult for me. These are the lines that I can't understand in depth:

```
 1. (self.n_words, self.n_dim) = \
 2. self.word2id = {}, self.id2word = [], 
 3. self.embed = np.zeros((self.n_words, self.n_dim))
```

These are my questions:

- What does that **"= \"** mean on 1?
- Where **word2id**, **id2word** and **embed** are defined? Are they keywords of python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A backslash at the end of a line tells Python to extend the current logical line over across to the next physical line.
In your case, you can read the two lines as a single line:

```
(self.n_words, self.n_dim) = (int(x) for x in f.readline().rstrip('\n').split(' '))
```

In Python, a variable is created the moment you first assign a value to it (https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables.asp). 
So, word2id, id2word and embed are not keywords; they are created when a value is assigned to them.

Comment: So word2id, id2word and embed are following self because they are strictly used with self as attribute of that class?

Comment: Yes, they are attributes.